# How to add items from a Custom Alert Dialog to a listview?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

So I have already done this using Android's adapter and adapter and it is working just fine. The custom alert dialog has an edit text and when the user clicks okay, the name will be added to the listview.

But now, I am using a model and a custom adapter. How to do this?

Here is my code:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    EditText textsearch;
    ListView lv;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    ArrayList<Names> namesArrayList = new ArrayList<>(); //arraylist for names
    ArrayList<Names> findnames = new ArrayList<>(); //array list for search filter
    Adapter adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textsearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textsearch);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        adapter = new Adapter(this, namesArrayList);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        //
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        this.textsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                //using regular expression

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
//                findnames.clear();
//
//                //using regular expression
//                String s1 = s.toString();
//                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(s1);
//
//                for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
//                    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(list.get(i));
//                    if(matcher.find()){
//                        findnames.add(list.get(i));
//                    }//end if
//                }
//                //update the adapter
//                findadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.addmenu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id){
            case R.id.action_add:
                showDialog(); //calling the showDialog() method
                return true;

            default:
                 return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    public void showDialog(){
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
        dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

        final EditText textName = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editName);

        dialogBuilder.setTitle("New Item");
        dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                if(!textName.getText().toString().equals("")){
// code here to add item
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fields can not be empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });

        dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });
        AlertDialog build = dialogBuilder.create();
        build.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        this.namesArrayList.remove(position);
        this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name deleted!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

This is my model. Names.java

```
public class Names {
    String name;

    public Names(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Adapter.java

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    //data container
    ArrayList<Names> list;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    //constructor


    public Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<Names> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, parent, false);
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtname);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        //inflate
        holder.name.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder{
        TextView name;
    }
}
```

Comment: check my answer, hope it helps :p

Comment: consider marking my solution as an answer if you dont have any other questions, happy coding :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this :

```
if(!textName.getText().toString().equals("")) {
Names name = new Names(textName.getText().toString());
adapter.list.add(name);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();        
} else {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fields can not be empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Essentially, all i'm doing is making a new instance of a `Names` model and adding it to the list of items in the adapter